# were are my Bluetooth files stored?

Tags: bluetooth, directory

I downloaded 148 files from a friend, and was able to open only 6 of them. 
Where are the rest saved?

I have tried finding them in:

> videos -> photos -> album -> saved files

My storage shows memory used in the download but can't find were the files are.

Comment: Look in Downloads

Comment: simply search for one file and **open item location**

Comment: another note may these files name starting with **.** that mean hidden click `ctrl` + `H` to show hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jeremy31 said. Search in your Downloads Folder.

Try navigating to

> /home/"user"/Downloads

**or**

> /home/"user"/Public/

Where "user" is your Ubuntu Username, without the quotes (").